# Select tag doesn't inherit color from parent tag

Tags: html, css

I have a SELECT tag in a DIV. And I set color:#000 to DIV, but the content displayed in SELECT tag is blue which is the user agent stylesheet of iOS/Safari for select tag.
I think the color of SELECT should be inherited from its parent DIV tag because color is inevitable.Could anyone tell me the reason?

Sample code:

```css
div {
  color:#000
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option value="202211">202211</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

When access the HTML with iOS/Safari, the value 202211 will be displayed in blue which is user agent stylesheet of SELECT, not the color of his parent DIV tag.

Comment: You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Thank you @Gerard. It is what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inspector's "Computed" tab to see which property was applied and why.
Then just set

```
select {
  color: inherit;
}
```

if that's what you want